# Non-English text in mysql database is unreadable after server change

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have changed server from namecheap to vultr and exported/imported database but the non-english text in database is showing as unreadable text like this -> 
à®¨à¯†à®°à¯à®ªà¯à®ªà¯ à®Ÿà®¾.
How to solve this?
The character set of the exported file is UTF 8 itself.
php version is 5.6 and using serverpilot to setup the vultr server.

Comment: Which charset are you using for your connection? Have you used the proper collation for your columns?

Comment: @NicoHaase The charset is utf-8, the same database works well with namecheap shared server but on vultr, this is happening

Comment: TO be specific is utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was with the charset of each table was by default set to latin1_swedish_ci. I changed each and every table content to utf8_general_ci by selecting each table and changing the structure and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is happened while export database and import database. I also have same problem last a few months ago. What I did is I used exactly same charset while export and import.

**Export database**

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --default-character-set=utf8 USER_DATABASE > backup.sql
```

**Import database**

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD --default-character-set=utf8 USER_DATABASE < backup.sql
```

Hope this help.